# MySQL Query matching multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has a table that has different LIKES that people have. Each like is stored as a different record. The only info I have in each record is userID, likeID.

The search will be based on the current userID that is signed in. So I'm not matching EVERYONE with EVERYONE but instead matching EVERYONE vs 1

So userID 45 might have likeID 3, likeID 6 and likeID 22 in the table (for instance)

What I want to do is have the table return, in descending order userIDs that they match with based on the total likes they match with someone else.

For example, (based on user 45 example above) it would look at userID 1 and see how many of likeID 3, likeID 6 and likeID 22 they have. then it'd go to userID 2 and see how many of likeID 3, likeID 6 and likeID 22 they have.....it'd do this for everyone.

Then it'd show the results for any that have more than 0 matches for those 3 likeIDs:

Matches:

You and UserID 12 share 3 of the same likes.

You and UserID 87 share 3 of the same likes.

You and UserID 22 share 2 of the same likes.

You and UserID 73 share 2 of the smae likes.

You and UserID 71 share 1 of the same likes.

etc...

I hope that explains what I'm trying to do. I don't think the mySQL query will be too hard but right now I'm baffled at how to do it!

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
      UL2.userID,
      count(*) as LikeMatches
   from
      UserLikes UL1
         JOIN UserLikes UL2
            on UL1.LikeID = UL2.LikeID
           AND UL1.UserID != SingleUserBasisParameter
   where
      UL1.UserID = SingleUserBasisParameter
   group by
      UL2.UserID
   order by
      2 desc
```

The "2" in the order by is the ordinal column representing the COUNT(*)

Comment: @ypercube, Yup, but still good to see answers by other very talented minds like yourself too :)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!    Just wanted to let you know the code was actually: `AND UL2.userID != SingleUserBasisParameter where UL1.userID = SingleUserBasisParameter` instead of `AND UL1.UserID != SingleUserBasisParameter where UL1.UserID = SingleUserBasisParameter`

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid,count(*) as common_likes
from table
where likeid in (select likeid from table where userid = 45) and userid <> 45
group by userid
order by common_likes desc
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
SELECT COUNT(likes.likeID) as like_count FROM
LIKES as likes,
(SELECT UserID,likeID FROM likes WHERE UserID = $user_id) as user_likes
WHERE
user_likes.likeID = likes.likeID AND user_likes.userID != likes.userID
GROUP BY likes.UserID
ORDER BY like_count
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that it should at least give you the right idea. The 2nd SELECT finds all the likes of the main user, which you can then use to filter out the other likes.